# "On create" hook for markers/circles in Google Maps Javascript API v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I currently have a Google Map in my application with the drawing manager enabled. It currently reads from my database and populates the map with markers and circles from the data it retrieves. I can successfully use some hooks like "radius_changed" to save changes to the circles/markers back to the database. However, I can't seem to find an "onCreate" hook in the API to save data to the database when I draw a marker/circle on the map. Can anyone tell me how to do what I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Drawing manager has two events for your purpose:

`circleComplete`: This event is fired when the user has finished drawing a circle.

`google.maps.drawing.OverlayCompleteEvent` object, a more generic event

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DrawingManager